# why do we use ServletResponse object reference to call getWriter()

Tags: servlets

Why do we use `ServletResponse` object reference to call `getWriter()` method?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException {
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("text/html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't give much information. So I am just guessing what you need.

`HttpServletResponse` is an interface belonging to the `javax.servlet.http` package. It's super-interface `ServletResponse` declares the `getWriter()` method. Hence it is inherited by `HttpServletResponse`.

We can use an interface's reference to call a method on an object whose class implements the said interface. Hence we can call `getWriter()` on a reference of `HttpServletResponse`.